# Can't receive UDP packets wireshark sees them

Tags: centos, networking, udp

I have an application_A in `HOST_A` sending UDP messages. In `HOST_B` I am able to see the UDP packet in wireshark but `application_B` (running in `HOST_B`) doesn't receive them.

I can verify that `application_B` works because when I run `application_B` on `HOST_C` it properly receives the packets.

- `HOST_A`: Windows 10
- `HOST_B`: CentOS
- `HOST_C`: windows 8

What could cause the fact that I can see the packet in wireshark but the packets do not reach `application_B` in the CentOs machine.

Comment: Your CentOS machine might be dropping the packets according to a firewall config. I'm not sure what's enabled by default in CentOS, but you might want to take a look at [configuring it](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables)

Comment: You're sniffing packets on host b? Is appB on hostB listening to the port that the packets are being sent to? Also confirm etskinner 's firewall comment.

Comment: @etskinner I have taken a look to IP tables and added some rules. I will verify the solution as soon as possible. Please add your comment as an answer so that I can select it  as correct if the solution is correct.

Comment: Pleas post the output of `iptables -L`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CentOS machine might be dropping the packets according to a firewall config. I'm not sure what's enabled by default in CentOS, but you might want to take a look at [configuring it](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables). In iptables, ensure that there is an `ACCEPT` rule path for that type of packet.

There are also plenty of more user-friendly iptables alternatives if you're looking for a simple firewall (see [Firewalld](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/firewalls/introduction-to-firewalld-on-centos), [ufw](https://superuser.com/a/1035636/184755), others)